# libGDX X and Y MouseInput

Tags: java, libgdx, textures, sprite, mouseclick-event

I have a libGDX code, which I don't get why it doesn't work. 
My idea is the following: I create a sprite with a texture and if I click on this sprite, then something should happen. So far so good.

I create the sprite with the following code on position:
X = 0.1f;
Y = 0.5f;

This works fine...

```
            Sprite spr = new Sprite(texture);

        // Define sprite size to be 1m x 1m in game world
        spr.setSize(1, 1);

        // Set origin to sprite's center
        spr.setOrigin(spr.getWidth() / 2.0f, spr.getHeight() / 2.0f);

        // Calculate random position for sprite
        float randomX = 0.1f;
        float randomY = 0.5f;
        spr.setPosition(randomX, randomY);

        // Put new sprite into array
        testSprites[i] = spr;
```

Now I do want to get the X and Y Position of the mouse when I click.
But when I try it out with the Systemout, I get the following coordinates:
X Input: 748
X Sprite Position: 0.1

The Sprite position is correct, but the X Input (Gdx.input.getX) should be around 0.1 too, but is far of. Is there something I do not consider?

```
        if (Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Buttons.LEFT))
        System.out.println("X Input: "+ Gdx.input.getX());
        System.out.println("X Sprite Position: "+testSprites[1].getX());
```

Comment: instead of isButtonPressed you should use InputProcessor. Show render method. Did you project screen coordinates to world coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this article](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Coordinate-systems). You are comparing touch/mouse coordinates (pixels) with world coordinates (e.g. meters), without converting them. You can convert your input coordinates to world coordinates using the `unproject` method of your `Camera` or `Viewport`. You didn't provide enough information to see which you are using, but assuming you are using a `Camera` then you can do the following.

```
Vector3 mousePos = new Vector3();
camera.unproject(mousePos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
System.out.println("X Input: "+ mousePos.x);
```

Of course you should not use the `new` keyword in frequently called code, so you better move the `mousePos` variable to a class member.

Answer (score 0):

The position you get from the mouse are the screen coordinates. You need to project them (or rather unproject them) to world coordinates. Since you are using a `OrthographicCamera` this is a easy fix.

```
Vector3 mouse = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX, Gdx.input.getY, 0);
camera.unproject(mouse);

System.out.println(mouse);
```